# How to reduce lines with pipe in linux command line?

Tags: linux

Basically I just want to combine all lines into a single line in pipe.

e.g.,

```
# ls / | grep b
bin
boot
lib

# ls / | grep b | reduce
binbootlib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing `ls` output is not recommended as its brittle.

But as for your question you can do something like this:

```
$ls -1 / | grep b | paste -s -d ''
binbootlib
```

`ls -1` ensures single column format and `paste` combines all lines of text serially (`-s`) with delimiter (`-d`) as nothing `''`

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, :)

Answer (score 1):

besides the previous answer, an alternative will be just to remove the new line character:

```
$ ls / | grep b | tr -d '\n'
binbootlib
```